# Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/AutoComplete'

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-design, react-redux, material-ui

I installed material-ui-search-bar and then I want to use SearchBar. 
But I have next problem:

```
./node_modules/material-ui-search-bar/lib/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/AutoComplete' in '...node_modules/material-ui-search-bar/lib/components/SearchBar'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Next after install, you should import it in your script. See
[documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-search-bar)

Answer (score 45):

AutoComplete is associated with Lab package of material UI. On Adding the "lab" package AutoComplete can be used. Add using yarn

```
yarn add @material-ui/lab
```

or using npm

```
npm install @material-ui/lab
```

Comment: could you please , give more description here to understand

Answer (score 9):

I cannot upvote nor comment, so I just parrot the working solution.
Thanks, @blackspacer.

This works:

`npm install @material-ui/lab`

One expects all Material UI elements to be present after the initial package install, but there is an exception.

https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/

> **About the lab**
>
> This package hosts the incubator components that are not yet ready to
>   move to the core.
>
> Installation Install the package in your project directory with:
>
> // with npm
>
> `npm install @material-ui/lab`
>
> // with yarn
>
> `yarn add @material-ui/lab`

Answer (score 6):

Install material-ui using this command :

```
npm install material-ui@latest
```

Answer (score 3):

This can happen due to multiple reasons.

1) You are using the beta version of v1.0 launch of material-ui which has breaking changes. Try switching to the stable version. Or if you want to use the latest beta version, then use  
Refer below link:
https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete/[material-ui AutoComplete](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/autocomplete/)

2) Try importing like below:

```
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
```

or

```
import { AutoComplete } from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
```

Due to the port going on for @next version the modules are being reorganized and hence few components are breaking.

Answer (score 3):

Use `npm i @autocomplete/material-ui` in your terminal.

Then run `npm start`, issue will be resolved.

```
import { Autocomplete } from '@autocomplete/material-ui';
```

Further more information or to try the template on another file for testing - use the below reference link.
[1]:https://www.npmjs.com/package/@autocomplete/material-ui

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that worked is uninstall material-ui-search-bar and install using npm install material-ui-search-bar@beta

Answer (score 1):

npm -i @material-ui/core

as more packages may be needed. For me besides lab i also needed utils. Hope this helps.

Comment: no need for `-i`. it should be `npm i @material-ui/core`

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn add material-ui-icons
```

Try using this in project directory

Comment: ```yarn add @material-ui/icons``` if you are using importing `import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';`

Answer (score 0):

Install beta version `npm install material-ui-search-bar@beta`
My issue got resolved after installing beta version.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 4 years old so some of the answers here are no more correct. In 2022 and on v5.5, **this is no more a lab component**, but another reason you might be still getting this error:

> export 'AutoComplete' (imported as 'AutoComplete') was not found in '@mui/material'

is if you're still using the old name. Its name has changed from "Auto**C**omplete" to "Auto**c**omplete", i.e., the letter c is no more capital.

So if you have something like:

```js
import AutoComplete from @mui/material/AutoComplete
```

...just change it to this:

```js
import Autocomplete from @mui/material/Autocomplete
```

Answer (score 0):

import { Autocomplete } from '@mui/material';

Answer (score -1):

This is a nice example for your problem try it.

```
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab'
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are not importing Autocomplete correctly .

For more information [Visit here](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

Import like this.

```
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
```